# Click on div hides then shows next div on page?

Tags: jquery, css, click, hide, show

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/DW5CV/

I have started to put together this fiddle to try and work out how I can, with a very simple piece a jQuery, show the first full screen image when page loads, then when the user clicks on this image it is hidden and the next image on the page is shown and so on through many images. I know I could give them all individual id's and then write a very long piece of code that states each div but I wanted to learn how this can be done in a neater way?

```
  $('#img1').click(function() {
  $('#img2').show();
  $('#img1').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Put all the images you tend to show in an array. Then iterate over the array, thereby changing the src value of the image .use .show() and .hide() on each iteration of the array.

Comment: Should it behave like a loop (or) you want only one iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample fiddle, you can try something like the below:

```
$('.full').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.full').show();
});
```

Note: This will work for only one iteration. If you want it to loop, we can modify the code.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/DW5CV/9/)

**EDIT:** To get the loop working, modify the code as below. Basically we are checking if there is a `next` element (`div` containing the `img`) with `.full` class. If it exists, we `show` it. Else, we `show` the first element with `.full` class.

```
$('.full').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    if($(this).next('.full').length === 1)
        $(this).next('.full').show();
    else
        $('.full').eq(0).show();
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/DW5CV/12/)

Comment: thanks, your fiddle works but when i transfer it to my file I loose the  full screen aspect and it clicks to the next image but suddenly flicks back to the first image sraight away. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @angela: I have updated the answer. Please have a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I made a really simple fiddle based on your code. 
The images are animated with `.show()` and `.hide()` until the last one. Then the animation stops, since there are no images left.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdRB4/).

Answer (score 1):

I am no JQuery hero, but hopefully this helps you on your way:

HTML:

```
<div class="imageBox">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".imageBox img").hide();
    $(".imageBox img:first-child").show();
});

$(".imageBox img").on( "click", function() {
    if( $(this).next().length > 0 ) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".imageBox img:first-child").show();
    }
});
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/LhxBK/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Animate api of JQuery which can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.....

```
$('#img2').hide();
 $('#img1').click(function() {
  $('#img2').toggle();
  $('#img1').toggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well, try this.

```
$('.full').not(':first').hide();
 $('.full').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
 });
```

**[Woking Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DW5CV/11/)**